# Getting the non filtered values from a slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

_Hi, I try to calculate a table with the values that are NOT selected from my slicer 'Table'[Plan PT] with the following DAX formula :

```
Measure =
CALCULATETABLE(
    VALUES('Table'[Désignation]),
    FILTER(
        'Table',
        'Table'[Plan PT] <> SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Plan PT])
    )
)
```

But it's not working : when I replace selectedvalue with a fixed value ("3" for instance), it then works ?
Besides, how can I display this result in the filter context ? Shoul I need a disconnected Table ? Maybe another way ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you try with ALL('Table') inside FILTER instead of only 'Table'?

Comment: Thanks for your time : it works with the measure. If i use the same DAX calculation to create a table, then it does not work with selectedvalue ? How can i then display only the values that are not filtered ?

Comment: As per my knowledge, calculate table and measures are not same. You can change the value in a measure based on filter change, but this will not work similarly for a calculatetable. You can use constant or stating value to filter in a calculatetable function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Calculated Tables and Calculated Columns are calculated at dataset refresh time, and after that they are static. Meaning they will not be re-calculated during report view/interaction time.

Assuming you want to display a table visual (or any visual) that show all rows that haven't been selected then you can try the following.

You will need a separate table for your slicer as it is not possible to show rows outside of what has been sliced from the same table.

Create a Calculated Table that will be used for your slicer. For example:

```
Dim Plan PT = DISTINCT('Table'[Plan PT])
```

Next create a measure similar to:

```
Non-selected count = 
  var selected = DISTINCT('Dim Plan PT'[Plan PT])
  return CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Table'),
    NOT 'Table'[Plan PT] IN selected
  )
```

Then in your visual, add `[Non-selected count]` as a visual filter in the Filter pane on the right, and set it to `is not blank`.